# Spark data in memory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Im working with PySpark SQL and I want to retrieve tables from RedShift, save them in memory and then apply some joins and transformations. 
I want to apply that joins and transformation with the in memory data, not apply the sql plan created with the transformations directly to Redshift.

When Im retrieving the data it saves the schema only, right?

If I use createTempView() it saves a view in sparkcontext but not the data, right?

If I use cache() after get the dataframe it saves the data in memory? And the next transformations are applied in memory?

```
df = manager.session.read.jdbc(url=url, table=table, properties={"driver": driver, "user": user, "password": password})

df1 = manager.session.read.jdbc(url=url, table=table1, properties={"driver": driver, "user": user, "password": password})

df2 = manager.session.read.jdbc(url=url, table=table2, properties={"driver": driver, "user": user, "password": password})

df_res = df.union(df2)

df_res = df_res.groupBy("seq_rec", "seq_res").agg({'impuesto': 'sum'}).withColumnRenamed("SUM(impuesto)", "pricing")

df_result = df.join(df_res, [df.seq == df_res.seq_rec, df.res == df_res.seq_res])
```

After that I save the dataframe to an avro file, and is here where all the transformations are applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When Im retrieving the data it saves the schema only, right?

Yes, that is correct.

> If I use createTempView() it saves a view in sparkcontext but not the data, right?

Same here.

> If I use cache() after get the dataframe it saves the data in memory? And the next transformations are applied in memory?

No. It may cache data in memory, with fraction depending on the available resource, when dataset is first loaded. It won't fetch data eagerly.

There is old, and longer documented `CACHE TABLE` in SQL, which has been used to eagerly fetch data and attempt to cache it.

```
spark.sql("CACHE TABLE foo")
```